# Laravel 8 - Resource Route without Database Connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have created three routes:

[image: /web.php]

When I call `/cars/1` everything is correct and with mysql connected:

[image: /cars/1]

```
    App\Models\Car {#1543 ▼
      #fillable: array:12 [▶]
      **#connection: "mysql"**
      #table: "cars"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:15 [▶]
      #original: array:15 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

When I call `/salaries/22` there is no database connection:

[image: /salaries/22]

```
    App\Models\Salarie {#358 ▼
      #fillable: array:8 [▶]
      **#connection: null**
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: false
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: []
      #original: []
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

My Models and Controllers have no differences. I have already cleared the route cache and i have no idea left, why this is acting in different ways. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You can actually define a connection in your model. Maybe that happened? > protected $connection;

Comment: Do you have a id 22 in your salaries table? I think your model needs to be Salary instead of Salarie to work without defining the table in your model class

Comment: can you show to us the show method in your controller or any method that you use model binding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English singular of "salaries" is "salary", not "salarie".

Laravel is passing a variable named `$salary` due to your use of the `Route::resource()` method.

```php
Route::resource('/salaries', SalarieController::class)->middleware('auth');

// creates the show route
Route::get('/salaries/{salary}', ...);
```

Therefore, you must receive a `$salary` variable in your controller if you want to use the automatically generated resource routes.  I suspect you are attempting to receive a variable named `$salarie` which does not exist.

```php
public function show(Salarie $salary)
{
    // ...
}
```

It may be simplest to rename the model to `Salary` (plus singular variables to `$salary`) and the controller to `SalaryController` to avoid further confusion.

Comment: oh my god, thank you! so stupid...
is it possible to set this behavior individually? or also for another language?

Comment: You can define each route individually instead of using `::resource()`. Then you can make the variable passed whatever you want.  For other languages, you would probably have to modify the "Pluralizer" by adding your own "irregular" definitions. I have never needed to do this myself, but I imagine those two words may help you to find examples.

Comment: Ok, pluralizer looks good for me. Thank you